# Rx operator that starts like combineLatest but then acts like withLatestFrom

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactivex

I am looking for an operator that combines two `Observables` by not emitting anything until both `Observables` have emitted an element (similar to `combineLatest`), but then only emits elements by combining elements from one `Observable` with the most recently emitted element of the other `Observable` (similar to `withLatestFrom`). The results would look like this (`y` observable is the "control"):

[image]

Does an operator like this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I solved this in Java, but the same theory should work for you.*

What you have is really two basic patterns; A `combineLatest` value followed by `withLatestFrom` values. If `withLatestFrom` triggers first then you want to skip the `combineLatest` value.

Start by making the `withLatestFrom` observable:

```java
Observable<Result> wlf = o1.withLatestFrom(o2, f::apply);
```

Next we want to create the `combineLatest` observable that emits a single value. We also want to stop this observable when `wlf` triggers:

```java
Observable<Result> cl = Observable.combineLatest(o1, o2, f::apply)
    .take(1).takeUntil(wlf);
```

Finally add these two observable together... For convenience I made a helper method to accept any two observables and a bi-function operator:

```java
public static <Result,
    Param1, Source1 extends Param1,
    Param2, Source2 extends Param2>
Observable<Result> combineThenLatestFrom(
    final Observable<Source1> o1,
    final Observable<Source2> o2,
    final BiFunction<Param1, Param2, Result> f
) {
    final Observable<Result> base = o1
        .withLatestFrom(o2, f::apply);
    return Observable
        .combineLatest(o1, o2, f::apply)
        .take(1).takeUntil(base)
        .mergeWith(base);
}
```

And here's the test code I used to verify the method:

```java
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    final TestSubject<String> o1 = TestSubject.create(scheduler);
    final TestSubject<String> o2 = TestSubject.create(scheduler);
    final Observable<String> r = combineThenLatestFrom(o1, o2, (a, b) -> a + b);
    r.subscribe(System.out::println);
    o1.onNext("1");
    o1.onNext("2");
    o2.onNext("A");
    o2.onNext("B");
    o2.onNext("C");
    o2.onNext("D");
    o1.onNext("3");
    o2.onNext("E");
    scheduler.triggerActions();
}
```

Which outputs:

```
2A
3D
```

Comment: thanks! instead of doing the `takeUntil(wlf)` and `mergeWith(wlf)` can't you replace those both with a `switchLatest`? something like: `Observable.of(cl.take(1), wlf).switchLatest()`?

Comment: @ScottH i think that would also work, but im not sure if `cl` has the posibility of ending the `wlf` stream. At least with `takeUntil` we know that only `cl` will be ended. If switch does work then i agree it will look cleaner; just make sure to add unit tests!!!

Comment: I had to make o1 and o2 connectible(publish().refCount()) in order for it to work properly, due to what I suspect was the cause of the duplicate emissions with cold observables.

Answer (score 0):

It ain't pretty, but this works (in C#):

```
var xs = new Subject<string>();
var ys = new Subject<int>();

var query =
    Observable
        .Merge(
            xs.Select(x => new { xt = true, yt = false, x, y = default(int) }),
            ys.Select(y => new { xt = false, yt = true, x = default(string), y }))
        .StartWith(new { xt = false, yt = false, x = default(string), y = default(int) })
        .Scan((a, b) => new
        {
            xt = a.xt && a.yt ? false : a.xt || b.xt,
            yt = a.xt && a.yt ? false : a.yt || b.yt,
            x = b.xt ? b.x : a.x,
            y = b.yt ? b.y : a.y
        })
        .Where(z => z.xt & z.yt)
        .Select(z => z.y + z.x);

query.Subscribe(v => Console.WriteLine(v)); 

ys.OnNext(1);
ys.OnNext(2);
xs.OnNext("A");
xs.OnNext("B");
xs.OnNext("C");
xs.OnNext("D");
ys.OnNext(3);
xs.OnNext("E");
```

It gives:

```
2A
3D
```

Comment: I think you may have over-engineered this a little :-)

Comment: @flakes -Possibly.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity! I like @flakes answer better because it is a pretty simple composition of basic Rx operators, but I appreciate the effort!